# jQueryUI autocomplete - AND/OR conditions in the select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/BXYpt/ from [jQuery UI autocomplete with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866699/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-values) as the basis. This does exactly what I need it to except that I need to be able to have OR conditions. I've created a fiddle as a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/B8bWX/1/

My issue is this: the demo items are Car, Phone, and Car With Phone. Is there a way to make autocomplete handle three cases: the string contains case (the default) followed by an ANDed case and lastly by an OR case? So if I enter "Car Phone" it would result in:

1) first case - 0 results as "Car Phone" isn't a substring of any of the labels.

2) second case - 1 result because "Car" and "Phone" appear in "Car With Phone". This gets added to the list below the 0 results preceding.

3) third case - 2 more results are displayed because the labels "Car" and "Phone" contain at least one of the search items. These results appear below the previous results of stages 1 and 2 so the selection box below should now render:

Car With Phone

Car

Phone (Car and Phone order really don't matter as they're both equally right)

Here is the javascript in question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#topics" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: topics,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#topics" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#topics" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $("#topicID").val(ui.item.id);
        $( "#results").text($("#topicID").val());    
        return false;
    }
 })

});
```

So would it be possible to have it do in order:

1) string.contains (default)

2) string split --> AND condition

3) string split --> OR condition (no preference to sorting by the number of terms contained)

Comment: What do you mean by "ANDed" and all that?  _"So if I enter "Car Phone" it would attempt the ANDed case (0 results) and then follow up with the OR case..."_  That is pretty vague..

Comment: Sorry, I added in the comment but didn't retrofit the first sections. basically, split the string on the space and then searching with ANDs. So Car and Phone both appear in the string "Car With Phone" so they'd pass. I'll edit the upper section as well, thanks.

Comment: You would have to do it in the _opposite_ order then I think..  The first test (string.contains as you put it) will always result to `true` so the other two tests will never be reached.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm communicating it properly then. "Hello out there" contains "out there" so that would be true, but doesn't contain "there out" or "Hello there" (the "Hello there" sequence doesn't occur anywhere in "Hello out there" as the " out" is blocking). However, "Hello there" would pass both for the AND and OR condition (but it would be removed from the checking list via the AND)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we'll have to do is do our own search on the data for the "AND" and "OR" results. My first thought was to do this using the `response` event of the autoselect, and add the results to the ones gathered by the library itself. However, when writing it, I realized that I had to do the normal search anyway in order to prevent results showing up twice. Instead, I'll be specifying a function for the `source` property and do all the sorting myself.

(Using the earlier method, I also ran into a jquery-ui bug (with the new messages showing how many results were found) which does not come up with the newer approach.)

Well, it's pretty straight forward from here, so let me just show the code:

```
var topics = [
    {
    value: "carphone",
    label: "Car With Phone",
    id: "1"},
{
    value: "car",
    label: "Car",
    id: "2"},
{
    value: "phone",
    label: "Phone",
    id: "3"}
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#topics").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#topics").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#topics").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#topicID").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#results").text($("#topicID").val());
            return false;
        },
        source: function(request, response) {
            var fullResults = [];
            var andResults = [];
            var orResults = [];
            var fullNeedle = request.term;
            var needles = $.grep(fullNeedle.split(" "), function(element) {
                return element !== '';
            });

            $.each(topics, function(key, topic) {
                var found = 0;
                $.each(needles, function(needleKey, needle) {
                    if (topic.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        found++;
                    }
                });

                if (topic.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(fullNeedle.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    fullResults.push(topic);
                }
                else if (found == needles.length) {
                    andResults.push(topic);
                }
                else if (found > 0) {
                    orResults.push(topic);
                }
            });

            $.merge(fullResults, andResults);
            $.merge(fullResults, orResults);
            response(fullResults);
        }
    });
});
```

A little explanation: we don't give our topics to the library anymore as the source, but instead we're keeping the source for ourselves as we search through it ourselves. We do this using three arrays, each one of which will contain one of the three types of results, so we can keep the order correct. Finally, we merge the three arrays after we're done populating them.

Comment: This works and puts me in a good spot to apply logic to filter and/or change the list as was brought to my attention yesterday. I saw a remotely similar option in using grep but it involved regular expressions which I have zero clue about (nor did it really handle the separate case scenarios). This does exactly as needed and a big perk is that I'm going to need to toss in some logic (filter list by a control on the form, but if no results then pull from another list, etc.). Perfect.