# send userID from handler to aspx page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, handler

I am working on asp.net. I have applied full text search functionality using handler. And now I want that when user chooses a name from list (which is suggested after entering keywords) page should be redirected to that person's profile.

```
<link href="Content/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete('Search_CS.ashx');
});
 </script> 

<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="search" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="search_Click" />
```

When a user types a name in textbox, it returns usernames with matching search text. It is handling in handler(ashx file)

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Profile_ID,FirstName, LastName from UserProfile where FirstName like '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR LastName like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["FirstName"]).Append(" ").Append(sdr["LastName"]).Append(Environment.NewLine);

                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Now when user types "Tom" a list is opened with all the users having name "tom". When user selects "Tom John", page should navigate to Tom John profile. How to redirect user to particular user's profile page?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect methods in search_Click?

The answer to your question - how to get Profile_Id for given user selected in autocomplete is provided here:

[jQuery UI Autocomplete with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866699/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-values)

Comment: yes it can be done but the main issue which I am facing is I don't know that how to pick that Profile_ID whose username is selected by the user

Comment: That question is probably already solved then - check the provided link.

Comment: This is probably not what I want. I am matching input to sql record

Comment: To match this you need a value of Profile_Id and the article states how to have a autocomplete list with names and alongside to read id of selected item from that. If this is not what you want then describe it further.